# What ways are there to send images (png, jpg...) with JSON?

Tags: json, image, base64, send

I know of base64 and those can easily be sent through JSON, as they are strings. Are they some other ways? Is is possible to send it as bitmap and how effective would that be? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is the only direct method but i'd avoid it for images larger than a couple of kB, it clutters what are usually short succinct messages.

Normally I would prefer to host it and provide the URLs for the image.

Comment: Which specific part? Handling image uploads? File system access? What language/frameworks/architecture are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Base64 is only way to sent images in JSON as base64 can be sent in String format.

And base64 images are 37% more than original image in size, if this is avoidable and image URLs can be sent, the please prefer that.